# Response.Write in a Shared function

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to open a new window from a shared function? There is a compile time error on the line that starts: `Response.Write`:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function UpdateTimeBasedDisposal(ByVal usn As String, ByVal strCon As String, ByVal decision As String, ByVal review As String) As String
        Dim boolDecision As Boolean = CType(decision, Boolean)
        Dim objNominal As New clsPrimaryNominal(strCon)
        Dim strUpdateTimeBasedDisposal As String = ""
        Dim objReview As New clsReviews(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GeniedbConnection").ConnectionString), tyReview As New typeReview, intTotal As Integer, intDisposalTotal As Integer, intType As Integer

        If boolDecision Then
            If objNominal.MakeTimeBased(CInt(usn)) < 1 Then
                strUpdateTimeBasedDisposal = "THERE WAS A PROBLEM MAKING THE NOMINAL RECORD FOR " & usn & " TIME BASED DISPOSAL." & vbCrLf
            Else
                strUpdateTimeBasedDisposal = "The Primary Nominal was successfully put into time based disposal"
            End If
        Else
            If objNominal.MakeNotTimeBased(CInt(usn)) < 1 Then
                strUpdateTimeBasedDisposal = "THERE WAS A PROBLEM MAKING THE NOMINAL RECORD FOR " & usn & " NOT TIME BASED DISPOSAL." & vbCrLf
            Else
                strUpdateTimeBasedDisposal = "The Primary Nominal was successfully taken out of time based disposal"
                ' next thing to do is create all the disposal records
                'CreateDisposals()
                intType = objReview.ReviewType(CLng(review), intTotal, intDisposalTotal)
                Response.Write("<script>window.open('frmNRAC.aspx?USN=" & CStr(Session("PNUSN")) & "&Review=" & CStr(Session("Review")) & "&Total=" & intTotal & "&Disposals=" & intDisposalTotal & "','_blank')</script>")
            End If
        End If
        Return strUpdateTimeBasedDisposal
    End Function
```

Comment: It's possible if you have the page as a parameter. But idealy the function wouldn't call Response.Write, the function would instead return a value indicating if the caller should do a Response.Write

Comment: Also: hungarian notation is now specifically discouraged, even by Microsoft's own style guidelines for .Net

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, I agree with your point about Hungarian noptation.  The previous developer used it for two years before I started in 2011 and I have used it since.  Best to be consistent; don't you think? Did you see my comment under your answer? +1.

Comment: @ Joel Coehoorn, do you think it is better to be consistent?

Comment: Mostly, but occasionally you have to draw lines to avoid perpetuating weak practices.

Answer (score 2):

This is server-side code. Server-side code can *never* directly open a new window. All it can do is create an http response that causes some **javascript** to open a new window. WebMethods also can't call the javascript on their own directly. You need code at the call site for the webmethod to invoke your javascript based on the result of the method.

Additionally: beware `Shared` methods in ASP.Net in the first place. They share data at the application domain level, and in ASP.Net, all the users of your site are in the same application domain.

Comment: Thanks could you confirm what you mean by your second paragraph.  I understand session state; application state etc.  If two users access the shared function at the same time then will they will not share the local variables e.g. boolDecision? For example, if one sets to true and the other sets to false then there won't be an issue because they have different copies? Is that correct? +1.

Comment: In this case, because the method is Shared, you don't know _at compile time_ which Response to write to, or if there even is one. You need the context of a specific Page instance. The Response variable works because it provided as a member of your page instance.

Comment: is there any risk "sharing data at the application level"?

Comment: Yes, there are risks.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate slightly on that before I mark your answer as accepted? Thanks again.

Comment: I've Shared methods cause applications to show one user data belonging to another user.

Comment: this is concerning me a little.  I thought the only way this could happen is if you use the application object e.g. application("UserName")? Is that not correct? Are there any other questions you could refer me to.  Thanks again.